# Font size respond to fill 100% width of parent div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, responsive-design

I'm trying to get the contents of a h1 element to adjust the font size in order to ensure that the text fills exactly 100% of the width of its parent div.

I've tried a few different plugins, including fittext.js, slabtext.js and bigtext.js, but can't get any to work.

Does anyone have any idea how I could get this kind of effect in the example below for the .sectionTitle h1 elements.

Codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/NpYJKK.

Example HTML:

```
 <section id="contact">

   <div class="sectionContent">

     <h1 class="sectionTitle">Contact</h1>

   </div>

 </section>
```

Comment: Maybe if you use a span inside the h1 you could programatically increase the span's font size until the span width matches the h1 width.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean or how I'd do that.

Comment: Please don't attempt to remove your question via vandalism. If you want to communicate with other posters, you can leave a comment on your question, or even edit it to add notes, but you shouldn't remove the content itself, especially when there are upvoted answers on it.

Answer (score 0):

[FitText.js](http://fittextjs.com/) should do what you need.

Add the [necessary js files](https://github.com/davatron5000/FitText.js), and then add this line to your code:

```
jQuery(".sectionTitle").fitText(.5);
```

Note that a compression value of `.5` seemed to be necessary to make your text stretch full width.

**[codepen demo](https://codepen.io/sol_b/pen/jBzJGM)**

Comment: Only one of the elements actually fills the full width of the viewport